# I thought ANDROID_ID never changes but I was wrong

Tags: android

I thought ANDROID_ID never changes but I was wrong

I use this code,

```
private String getUser() {
    return Settings.Secure.getString(myContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
}
```

however, I've seen it change spontaneously on my phone , Other than that, how do I get uniqe key, without asking permission from the user ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids).

Google have already shared some best practices to how generate and work with unique ids.

Comment: I am looking now

Comment: Ok, but I can answer to you now that in Mobile we should not use a Hardware ID. The recommended approach is to use an installation ID generated programmatically with UUID.